# How can I add claims to the context for GetProfileDataAsync & IsActiveAsync for a custom user service?

Tags: identityserver3

I am implementing a [user service](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/userService.html) that is storing user info in Azure Table storage. I would like to use a value for tenant ID as part of my partition key, but, the claims available in GetProfileDataAsync and IsActiveAsync are just 5 built in claims (sub, name, amr, idp, auth_time).

I get tenant ID from my identity provider and it's included as a claim in both my access token & identity token. How can I make it available to those methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `AuthenticateLocal` is invoke, you return an `AuthenticateResult` to indicate the authentication outcome. If it's successful you use the ctor overload that accepts the `subject` and `name` values. There's also an optional `claims` collection. If you pass values for `claims` then you are adding your own custom claims to the authentication cookie at IdentityServer. Those claims are then part of the `Subject` for the `GetProfile` API (assuming the requests into those APIs are being done via the browser such as from the authorization request). You can then inspect those claims and use them in any way you want.

If the request is not via the browser, then the only claim you have on the `Subject` is the user's unique id (which is the `sub` claims).

Comment: This does work for some requests, but not for calling the UserInfo endpoint later on (where as you mention there's only Subject). I've ended up encoding this information in the Subject of my users, and creating 2 records in the same partition for efficient querying in Table storage.

Comment: Correct -- and if you re-read you will see I wrote `"assuming the requests into those APIs are being done via the browser such as from the authorization request"`.

Comment: I want to use custom added claim to be passed to Web API in access_token. How can i do that ?